# Assign a combined string to href tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have some rows in a table I want to set every row as a link by using href tag in HTML. The structure of my links is something like this:

> http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/oval-definition-details.php?ovaldefinitionid=oval%3Aorg.mitre.oval%3Adef%3A9278&s=1

I want to set "org.mitre.oval" and "9278" parts as a variable so I can change them based on the value of each row. something like this:

```
 X and Y are variables
 <a href = "http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/oval-definition-details.php?ovaldefinitionid=oval%3A" + X +"%3Adef%3A" + Y + "&s=1" >row</a>
```

but href tag does not support this kind of concatenation. 
Any idea how can I seperate those parts and put my values in them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following demo is a solution for multiple links.

### Demo

```js
var xArray = ['2813224', '8472040'];
var yArray = ['zer00ne', 'afsane'];
var lnx = document.links;

for (let i = 0; i < lnx.length; i++) {
  var X = xArray[i];
  var Y = yArray[i];
  var base = `https://stackoverflow.com/users/${X}/${Y}?tab=profile`;
  lnx[i].href = base;
  lnx[i].textContent = Y;
}
```

```html
<a href=''></a><br>
<a href=''></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't need the for so I just wrote it for one single X and one Y but as the other answer when I click on the link it reload current page. @zer00ne

Comment: Add `target="_blank"` to each `<a>` if you want links to jump to new page.

Comment: yes I did that but in the new tap it shows my page again. (like when you just write <a href = "" targer = "_blank">row</a>)

Comment: Right click the `<`a>` and see if it has an actual url in `href` ex. `href='http://example.com'`

Comment: you mean I should validate the URL? yes it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

try to add href in javascript :

```js
var X=1;
var Y=2;
var a = document.getElementById('mylink'); 
a.href = "http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/oval-definition-details.php?ovaldefinitionid=oval%3A" + X +"%3Adef%3A" + Y + "&s=1";
```

```html
 <a href = "" id="mylink" target="_blank">row</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I click on the link it shows my page again not the "a.href".

Comment: i tried it and it works with me try it in your code may be they prevent links to http or other websites

Comment: I removed href = "" and it works but I write this in a foreach and it just works for first iteration, for others it does not recognize javascript variable, do you know why? @SafaaAbdElHamid

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using template literal **``** and substitute using ${varaiable}[template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```html
 <a href=`http://www.itsecdb.com/oval/oval-definition-details.php?ovaldefinitionid=oval%3A${X}%3Adef%3A${Y}&s=1` id="mylink">row</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but where should I define X and Y variables?